# Can different variables refer to the same object without an identity rule stated explicitly?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

For example, $\forall x(Qx\rightarrow \exists y(Py\wedge Rxy))$, if the Universe of discourse only contained one object, can this sentence be true?

Comment: Yes sorry I did make a typo, I just edited it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, different variables can refer to the same referent even if equality is not explicitly stated in the sentence in question. For example, in a structure with a single element the sentence $$\forall x\forall y(Px\leftrightarrow Py)$$ is always true.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, $\forall x(Qx\rightarrow \exists y(Py\wedge Rxy))$, if the Universe of discourse only contained one object, can this sentence be true?

Certainly.  In the universe of exactly *one red apple*: $\forall x~(x\text{ is an apple}\to\exists y~(y\text{ is red}\wedge x=y))$